# how do I get rid of [Object: null prototype] in visual studio terminal nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to get rid of the `[Object: null prototype]` in the terminal so it will only display `{id: '1'}` ?

[image: the console image]

```
const data = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/dev-data/data.json` , 'utf-8');
const dataObj = JSON.parse(data);

const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    console.log(url.parse(req.url, true));
    const { query, pathname } = url.parse(req.url, true);
    console.log(query);
});
```

Comment: That's a *very useful* piece of information, it indicates that the object does not inherit from `Object.prototype` If it were me, I'd keep it

Comment: how this info useful?

Comment: It indicates whether you can call `Object.prototype` methods on it, For example: `hasOwnProperty`, `isPrototypeOf`, `toString`, `valueOf`, `__proto__`. Possible for normal objects, but not for objects which do not inherit from `Object.prototype`

Comment: so should i keep it , cause it will help me in the future or ?

Comment: You could, it might help. But it's up to you. (either way, I don't know how to configure the log unfortunately, sorry)